# Unable to get product weight in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to get product weight in my plugin to show it on sidebar in separate input box. But I am unable to get the product weight.

Please take a look at my code and help me to get the product weight from WooCommerce product:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Calculator
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/
 * Description: Calculate
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: wtm
 * Author URI: http://wtynet.com
 */

if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

if ( !in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) return; // Check if WooCommerce is active

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'showtest', 10 );
function showtest(){

$prweight = WC_Product::get_weight();
echo "<div style='border: 2px solid #43515f; padding: 10px; text-align:center;'>";

your_css_and_js();
echo "<input id= 'prweight' type='text' value='".$prweight."'>";

echo "</div>";

}

function your_css_and_js() {
wp_register_style('your_css_and_js', plugins_url('css/style.css',__FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_style('your_css_and_js');
wp_register_script( 'your_css_and_js', plugins_url('js/script.js',__FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_script('your_css_and_js');

}

?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested your code and I have changed a little bit this part, to get the weight:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'showtest', 10 );

function showtest(){
    global $product;

    $prweight = $product->weight;
    // or
    // $prweight = $product->get_weight();

    echo '<div style="border: 2px solid #43515f; padding: 10px; text-align:center;">';

    your_css_and_js();
    echo '<input id="prweight" type="text" value="'.$prweight.'">';

    echo '</div>';
}
```

This is tested and works.

Comment: Thank you dear, It really fixed my problem :)